# Microsoft bluetooth mouse 3600 - Not set up

Tags: mouse

I have a HUAWEI Matebook D14, running Ubuntu 20.04. I installed it and all works perfect. But my Microsoft Bluetooth mouse 3600 does not set up, does not connect to my computer. The computer see the mouse, but does not set up it. All my other Bluetooth devices did set up and connected perfect.

Can anyone please help me how to fix it?

Comment: 1) There is no Ubuntu 20.01. 2) Did you press the pairing button of the mouse? Read the mouse manual.

Comment: Sorry, Ubuntu 20.04. Yes, I press the pairing button of the mouse. The computer see the mouse.